# Replacing drywall above boiler... to Code? Inspection?

Tags: drywall, code-compliance, boiler

I own a mid-1800's house in New England, with a fieldstone foundation and dirt floor basement. I now have a mold problem in the basement.

There is lone sheet of drywall above the boiler & water heater, presumably as fire protection. Among my many problems, that drywall is covered in mold and must be replaced.

My question: is this something that might need to be done to code, with an inspection, etc.? Should I call my town about it?

Comment: In an old house such as yours, that lone sheet of drywall may be asbestos if it was installed before 1989 when it was officially banned by the EPA. It was stopped being used in production in 1978.

Comment: Yes you should contact your local government to determine what the requirements are in your area.  Since you're having trouble with moisture and mold, you should inquire about methods to meet the requirement that also take these problems in to consideration.

Comment: Don't bother replacing the drywall until you fix the moisture problem or you will just have the same problem over and over.